# Setting and getting values from a x-y graph

Tags: php, graph

I have a bunch of x-y graphs given to me and I need to be able to transform them into some kind of data structure from which I will be able to get Y with X value.
The problem is, though that I have 4, at max 5 values of Y given to me, and my X values can range up to 9000. So the information I have is something of the form

```
Point # X       Y
1       1000    100
2       3250    460
3       6000    320
4       6500    300
```

My idea initially was something like:

```
function getY($x){
    $data[1000] = 100;
    $data[3250] = 460;
    $data[6000] = 320;
    $data[6500] = 300;

    if(isset($data[$x])){
        return $data[$x];
    }

    $minKnown = null;
    $maxKnown = null;

    foreach($data as $_x => $y){
        if($_x < $x){
            $minKnown = $_x;
        }

        if($_x > $x){
            $maxKnown = $_x;
            break;
        }
    }

    return $data[$minKnown] + (($x - $minKnown) / ($maxKnown - $minKnown)) * ($data[$maxKnown] - $data[$minKnown]);
```

}
    }

This function I just wrote to illustrate my idea. Basically if a point is not defined but somewhere between 2 known points, assuming there are no curves between the two points get the value that co-responds to the position of X between the two known values of X. I'm not even sure if my verbal explanation is actually correct or not but I guess that's what I wrote the function for.

Anyway, I was thinking, since graphs something that's widely used, are there any better ways of doing this, and I'm hoping there are otherwise I might turn out to be smarter than I thought, which is scary.

Comment: I think you are looking for either "linear interpolation" (with multiple points - which is what you're doing here!) or "splines" (different types but basically ways to approximate those curves - see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) for more details). Unfortunately I don't see any good PHP libraries for this right away, unless you're trying to just plot smooth curves on the graph. Good job on getting something working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said, that you assume that there are no curves, the graph itself would probably look like a stock development. So I would try a vector calculation approach. 
With the data you gave in your example you would get 3 vectors defined by two points. (To generalize it, you would get one vector less then you got points.)

In your example:

Vector1: Point1->Point2 (Point2[x] - Point1[x], Point2[y] - Point1[y])
 
Vector2: Point2->Point3 (Point3[x] - Point2[x], Point3[y] - Point2[y])
Vector3: Point3->Point4 (Point4[x] - Point3[x], Point4[y] - Point3[y])

With values:

Vector1: (3250 - 1000, 460 - 100) = (2250, 360)
Vector2: (6000 - 3250, 320 - 460) = (2750, -140)
Vector3: (6500 - 6000, 300 - 320) = (500, -20)

Now the standard linear function has the form y = m*x + b. The vector itself won't need the b. So for Vector1 it is: 360 = m * 2250 
Resolved for m we get: m = 360 / 2250 = 0.16
Now we get back to the original line between P1 and P2, which will require a value for b.
We get this now with: 100 = 0.16 * 1000 + b => b = -60
With that we know each y value between Point1 and Point2 will be defined by this equation: y = 0.16 * x - 60.
You can check this by simply inserting the values of one of the points into the equation:
P1 100 = 1000 * 0.16 - 60 
P2 460 = 3250 * 0.16 - 60

Code example:

```
$vector1x = $Point2->X - $Point1->X;
$vector1y = $Point2->Y - $Point1->Y;

$m1 = $vector1y / $vector1x
$b1 = $Point1->y - $Point1->x * $m1
// do the same for the other points as described.
```

Now when you get a value for x which you want to get the y value of do sth like this:

```
function getY($x)
{
    if($x >= $Point1->X && $x <= $Point2->X)
    {
        $y = $m1 * $x + $b1;
    }
    else if($x <= $Point3->X)
    {
        $y = $m2 * $x + $b2;
    }
    else if($x <= $Point4->X)
    {
        $y = $m3 * $x + $b3;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Cannot calculate value with given data!");
    }
    return $y; 
}
```

I hope this approach serves your needs and helps you in solving the problem.